# Animation with multiple background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

I am trying to create some animations for my multiple background images.

I have this CSS code:

```
header {
background-image: url('/img/cloud2.png'), url('/img/cloud3.png'), url('/img/cloud1.png'), url('/img/cloud4.png');
background-position: left bottom, 20% 40%, 40% bottom, right 85%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I just want to move the clouds around in a infinite loop. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
  $('header').animate({
    'background-position-x': '10%, 3%, 5%, 7%'
  }, 500, 'linear');
```

The problem is that this doesn't work. It only works if I write just one background-position-x value. But in that case all of the clouds start from the same x value.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using `background-position` in the css and in the jquery you are using `background-position-x`.  Why not try resetting the `background-position` to the value you want using jquery?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Although, when I try to reset background-position with jquery, like this: `$('header').animate({ 'background-position': 'right bottom, 70% 70%, 80% 80%, 90% 90%' }, 500, 'linear');` all the background images move forward to the first position mentioned (right bottom). What I want to do is move each background image to a different position...

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your exact problem and then I might be able to help you? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yeah, sorry! :) It's here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TqtPt/1/), although it's not moving (i don't know why...). What I want to do is move each cloud to a different position...